# SwiftUI Init method does not work with ObservedObject Declaration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to create a tabbed application in Swift using Swift UI. I am using @ObservedObject to store the current view name that should be rendered.

I am trying to change the background color of the UI Tab Bar however every time I add the init to override the method begins chucking errors such as "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments".

I have attached a snippet of the controller code below. Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    @ObservedObject var coreRouter: CoreRouter

    init() {
         UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
     }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text("First Screen")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
            }
            .tag(0)
            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("calendar")
                        Text("New Items")
                    }
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(coreRouter: CoreRouter())
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `init` needs to accept a `coreRouter` argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `ContentView` has a `coreRouter` property, your `init` needs to accept a value to assign to that property;

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    @ObservedObject var coreRouter: CoreRouter

    init(coreRouter: CoreRouter) {
         self.coreRouter = coreRouter
         UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
     }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:
(i had to create a dummy class, because you did not provide the code for corerouter)

```
class CoreRouter : ObservableObject {

    @Published var a = false

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    @ObservedObject var coreRouter: CoreRouter

    init() {
        coreRouter = CoreRouter()
         UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
     }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text("First Screen")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Home")
                    }
            }
            .tag(0)
            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image("calendar")
                        Text("New Items")
                    }
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```